# Why do I get "..::b is private within this context"

Tags: c++, g++

Here is the context.. I'm compiling with g++.

```
template<typename T>
class Array;

template<typename T>
int length(Array<T>& a);

template<typename T>
class Array
{
public:
  //...
private:
  T* a;
  int b;
  template<typename>
  friend int length(Array<T>&);
};

template<typename T>
int length(Array<T>& a)
{
  return a.b;
}
```

Is there a way to always declare "the corresponding friend length function" (i.e. length) if "the class is defined (i.e. Array)?

I thought maybe explicitely instantiate it like..

```
...

template<typename T>
class Array
{
public:
  ...

private:
  ...

  template int length<T>(Array<T>&);
  friend int length(Array<T>&);
};

...
```

NOTE: the above doesn't compile

Comment: `Array<int>` has the friend(s) `template<typename> int length(Array<int>&)`, which is not the same as `template<typename T> int length(Array<T>&)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply need to fix the declaration:

```cpp
private:
  T* a;
  int b;
  
  friend int length<>(Array<T>&);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
template<typename T>
class Array
{
public:
  //...
private:
  T* a;
  int b;
  friend int length<>(Array&);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/59vzEEvzq)

Your `template<typename /*U*/> friend int length(Array<T>&);` doesn't match outside template.

Comment: `Your template<typename /*U*/> friend int length(Array<T>&); doesn't match outside template.` Nonsense, friend int length(Array<T>&) would resolve to friend int length(Array<int>&), which would match..
template<typename T>
int length(Array<T>&);

Comment: I explicitly `/*U*/` to show the mismatch with `T`. `Array<int>` will have as `friend` `template <typename T> int length(Array<int>&)` (non deducible T), and not `template <typename T> int length(Array<T>&)` (with `T=int` or not).

Answer (score -1):

I think you can fix  your code like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Array
{
public:
  //...
  int getB() { return b;};
private:
  T* a;
  int b;
  template<typename>
  friend int length(Array<T>&);
};

template<typename T>
int length(Array<T>& a)
{
  return a.getB();
}
```

Comment: That would make the code compile, but it doesn't answer the question about why length() cannot access b.